# Recover lost space on USB HDD after image burning by Unetbootin

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

2019-05-29
A 16  Gb USB HDD (thumb drive) turned into an 8 Gb total after burning  ubuntu 19.04 by unetbootin .  The thumb drive does allow me to boot ubuntu without 
committing to permanent installation and use ubuntu but I noticed that about 8 GB of storage were lost.  Can the USB disk space be recovered and if so how?

Comment: The space comes back when you reformat your thumb drive back into non-bootable storage. The FAT filesystem used by the installer is limited to 8GB.

Comment: The following link may help, [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Postrequisites_-_restore_the_USB_stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Postrequisites_-_restore_the_USB_stick)

Comment: thank you very much for clarification on why the space disappeared and since I am planning on running as a live usb hdd (i.e. no dual boot or installation on my pc at this point) I accept the limitation and if I do go to dual boot I now know how to recover space